# Why I can tnsping Server P from Server A but cannot tnsping Server P from Server B?

Tags: oracle, tnsnames

Here is my situation:
I can ping P from both server A and Server B. But I just can tnsping Server P from A but not from B.

I checked the tnsnames.ora of A and B. They are identical. And I can tnsping other servers from B.

Any thought about it? Should I configure something on Server P?
Thanks a lot and have a great one!

Answer (score 1):

Ping uses ICMP, tnsping checks the connectivity of the host and port defined in the TNS entry.

> I checked the tnsnames.ora of A and B. They are identical.

Yes, and name resolution may be still different. Or more likely the firewall may block connection attempts from host B on the listener port.

Just use telnet, nc or whatever tool you have installed to check the host + port combination:

```
telnet serverP_ip_address listener_port
nc -z serverP_ip_address listener_port
echo 1 > /dev/tcp/serverP_ip_address/listener_port
```